AWS Mobile APP push notification explicity deny issue
I am trying to use push notification on the AWS Mobile APP for some alarms set up but receive this error message:
"Operation could not be performed
    
User: arn:aws:sts::AAAAAAA:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_BBBBBB/CCCCCC is not authorized to perform: notifications:CreateNotificationConfiguration on resource: arn:aws:notifications:us-east-1:AAAAAAA:configuration/* with an explicit deny"*

With AAAAAAA being the AWS account targeted |
BBBBB being the Admin Access ID |
CCCCC being the Admin email address.
Context:
The user CCCCC used (i.e. me) has full admin access. It has the AWS Policy AdministratorAccess attached which is
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Our AWS environment was set up by a 3rd party using AWS Control Tower Organizations.
I have checked the following:

The Permissions boundaries of the AWSAdministratorAccess permission set my user is mapped against - None set up.
All service Control Policies to any explicit deny for any mention of "notifications" -
None found.
All enabled Controls using AWS Control Tower for the account AAAAAAA for any reference of explicit deny of "notifications" - None found.

The closest thing I found would be that when in the AWS Mobile APP and selecting "notifications", it does not let you choose a region, however the error message implies I'm trying to access a resource in us-east-1 whereas my environment is in ap-southeast-2 and one of the AWS Control Tower enabled control is "[AWS-GR_REGION_DENY] Deny access to AWS based on the requested AWS Region"
SCP details:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:RequestedRegion": [
            "ap-southeast-2"
          ]
        },
        "ArnNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalARN": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSControlTowerExecution"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotAction": [
        "a4b:*",
        "access-analyzer:*",
        "account:*",
        "acm:*",
        "activate:*",
        "artifact:*",
        "aws-marketplace-management:*",
        "aws-marketplace:*",
        "aws-portal:*",
        "billing:*",
        "billingconductor:*",
        "budgets:*",
        "ce:*",
        "chatbot:*",
        "chime:*",
        "cloudfront:*",
        "cloudtrail:LookupEvents",
        "compute-optimizer:*",
        "config:*",
        "consoleapp:*",
        "consolidatedbilling:*",
        "cur:*",
        "datapipeline:GetAccountLimits",
        "devicefarm:*",
        "directconnect:*",
        "ec2:DescribeRegions",
        "ec2:DescribeTransitGateways",
        "ec2:DescribeVpnGateways",
        "ecr-public:*",
        "fms:*",
        "freetier:*",
        "globalaccelerator:*",
        "health:*",
        "iam:*",
        "importexport:*",
        "invoicing:*",
        "iq:*",
        "kms:*",
        "license-manager:ListReceivedLicenses",
        "lightsail:Get*",
        "mobileanalytics:*",
        "networkmanager:*",
        "notifications-contacts:*",
        "notifications:*",
        "organizations:*",
        "payments:*",
        "pricing:*",
        "quicksight:DescribeAccountSubscription",
        "resource-explorer-2:*",
        "route53-recovery-cluster:*",
        "route53-recovery-control-config:*",
        "route53-recovery-readiness:*",
        "route53:*",
        "route53domains:*",
        "s3:CreateMultiRegionAccessPoint",
        "s3:DeleteMultiRegionAccessPoint",
        "s3:DescribeMultiRegionAccessPointOperation",
        "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
        "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
        "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPoint",
        "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicy",
        "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicyStatus",
        "s3:GetStorageLensConfiguration",
        "s3:GetStorageLensDashboard",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
        "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
        "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
        "s3:PutMultiRegionAccessPointPolicy",
        "savingsplans:*",
        "shield:*",
        "sso:*",
        "sts:*",
        "support:*",
        "supportapp:*",
        "supportplans:*",
        "sustainability:*",
        "tag:GetResources",
        "tax:*",
        "trustedadvisor:*",
        "vendor-insights:ListEntitledSecurityProfiles",
        "waf-regional:*",
        "waf:*",
        "wafv2:*"
      ],
      "Sid": "GRREGIONDENY"
    }
  ]
}

I am running out of ideas and have not been able to find the solution yet despite googling this issue, reading AWS documentation etc.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Anyone had any ideas on how to resolve this?
